# I’m doing an exercise on javascript programming the direction are as follows

Tags: javascript

> Directions: Using the flowchart below, write the code to represent
>   checking your balance at the ATM. The yellow diamonds represent
>   conditional statements and the blue rectangles with rounded corners
>   represent what should be printed to the console. and  this is the
>   [link to flow chat](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud803/lessons/3ace947b-b5f6-40c1-bc11-3ec98fd1d936/concepts/03d8062f-6e1f-4f79-86e5-f49cde75e36d#)
>
> Use the following variables in your solution:
>
> balance – the account balance isActive – if account is active
>   checkBalance – if you want to check balance Hint: The variable balance
>   could be a value less than, greater than, or equal to 0. The variables
>   isActive and checkBalance are booleans that can be set to true or
>   false.
>
> TIP: To print out the account balance with decimal points (i.e.
>   325.00), use the .toFixed() method and pass it the number of decimal points you want to use. For example, balance.toFixed(2) returns
>   325.00.
>
> TIP: Make sure to test your code with different values. For example,
>
> If checkBalance equals true and isActive equals false, then Your
>   account is no longer active. should be printed to the console

This is my code (please point me to my mistake)

```js
var balance = 34;
var checkBalance = true;
var isActive = true;
// your code goes here
if (checkBalance === false) {
  console.log(“Thank You have a nice Day!”);
} else if (checkBalance === true && isActive === true && balance > 0) {
  console.log(“Your Balance is $” + balance.toFixed(2) + “.”);
} else if (checkBalance === true && isActive === false) {
  console.log(“You account is no longer Active”);
} else if (checkBalance === true && isActive === true && balance ===
  0) {
  console.log(“your account is empty”);
} else if (checkBalance === true && isActive === true && balance < 0) {
  console.log(“your balance is negative, please contact the bank”);
}
```

**The problem**: when I submit the quiz this is my feedback

> What Went Well
>
> – Your code should have a variable balance – Your code should have a
>   variable checkBalance – Your code should have a variable isActive –
>   Your code should include an if...else statement
>
> What Went Wrong
>
> – Verify that your if...else statement is producing the correct output
>   (REMEMBER: Test your code with different values)
>
> Feedback Not everything is correct yet, but you’re close

can anyone please help me out !!

I did saw a similar question to this  and compared their code to mines everything seems okay but mines won't work
could anyone point me to what  I'm doing wrong

Comment: You don't seem to have tested your code - the error is pretty much self explanatory

Comment: I've read your code now several times and I've seem to have missed what your error actually is...

Comment: @Pete — While there is an obvious error with the code, the question isn't asking about it. The error must have been introduced during the transcription of the code into the question.

Comment: @Elias — I think the question is "My assignment came back with an instruction to test it better. Please do that for me."

Comment: @Pete — Exactly.

Comment: @Pete — Yes, but *what went wrong* is "Verify that your if...else statement is producing the correct output (REMEMBER: Test your code with different values)"

Comment: @Pete — There are some hard-coded values at the top of the code. The description of the problem implies that when the code is run, it gives the expected output but that for some other values it does not give the expected output. The code in the question clearly does not give the expected output (which is an error, but not the one the question is asking about).

Comment: @Pete — Well, that would be a good way (ideally with a test library like Mocha) for the OP to identify what the problem actually is. Then they could ask a question with a [mcve] and a "clear problem statement".

Comment: @Pete i have tested the code and can't find what's wrong i have also researched my problem i saw some people did it successfully on GitHub
the links are : https://github.com/erikfenriz/Google-Developer-Challenge ( Quiz: Checking your Balance (3-5) ) 

https://gist.github.com/desinas/f366e069a524f025c203a2c8882501d3

but i want to find out what im doing wrong , I dont want to copy people code and over with please help out

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have used a non code editor
`console.log(“Thank You have a nice Day!”);` all the quotes are some kind of text editor quotes. The code should look like this: `console.log("Thank You have a nice Day!");` or this `console.log('Thank You have a nice Day!');`

Actually if you are new to programming I can imagine this to be quiet confusing. Now I would strongly suggest downloading some lightweight code editor. Here some good ones:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/ (My current daily driver)
- https://www.sublimetext.com/3
- https://atom.io/

Also I have written a little website where you can actively test the program (only works with integers though but you can happily add that feature :) )

```js
// Globals
var balance = 34;
var checkBalance = true;
var isActive = true;

// Getting DOM elements
const inputBalance = document.getElementById("inputBalance");
const inputCheckBalance = document.getElementById("inputCheckBalance");
const inputIsActive = document.getElementById("inputIsActive");

// Attach event listeners
inputBalance.addEventListener("input", () => {
  balance = parseInt(inputBalance.value);
  checkNow();
});

inputCheckBalance.addEventListener("input", () => {
  checkBalance = inputCheckBalance.checked;
  checkNow();
});

inputIsActive.addEventListener("input", () => {
  isActive = inputIsActive.checked;
  checkNow();
});

// Initialisation
inputBalance.value = balance;
inputCheckBalance.checked = checkBalance;
inputIsActive.checked = isActive;
checkNow();

// Create function
function checkNow() {
  // Check for balance
  if (checkBalance === false) {
    console.log("Thank You have a nice Day!");
  } else if (checkBalance === true && isActive === true && balance > 0) {
    console.log("Your Balance is $" + balance.toFixed(2) + ".");
  } else if (checkBalance === true && isActive === false) {
    console.log("You account is no longer Active");
  } else if (checkBalance === true && isActive === true && balance === 0) {
    console.log("your account is empty");
  } else if (checkBalance === true && isActive === true && balance < 0) {
    console.log("your balance is negative, please contact the bank");
  }
}
```

```html
<div><input tpye="number" id="inputBalance"><label>input Balance</label></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" id="inputCheckBalance"><label>input check Balance</label></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" id="inputIsActive"><label>input is Active</label></div>
```

Have a nice day :3

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't answer the question that is being asked. The errors you are discussing appear to have been introduced when transcribing the code into the question.

Comment: Well I couldn't have known that could I? I start at the top and stop at the first error...